# Get varying amout of values from argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I want to pars a color value from the command line. The color can either come as a RGB value or a RGBA value. Is it possible to tell argparse to get either the 3 or 4 next values or will I just have to take the remaining values and check that it is either 3 or 4 values or else print some sort of error to the user?

Comment: You will have to use '+' (or '*') and check the number of values yourself.  There isn't a 'range' `nargs` value.  `parser.error('your message here')` can be used to issue the `argparse` consistent error.

Comment: Thank you. Post that as an answer and I'll give you the credits for answering the question

Answer (score 0):

did you take a look at argparse?

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html

The example is actually rather fitting for your case

this program:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                   help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                   const=sum, default=max,
                   help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

takes integers as input, you should be able to use this?

Comment: Sorry could you be more specific? Which one of the multiple examples do you mean? I have tried to find the answer there but I did not manage.

Comment: The program they created takes integers as input, i added it to the answer, you should be able to use it.

Comment: But what I asked was if I manual have to check weather I got 3 or 4 arguments or if you can tell argparse to only accept 3 or 4 arguments, no more no less. So is your answer that that is the only way?

Comment: once you got the arguments, you have to code the verification that the correct number of integers was entered